# Table in dynamic columns that appears depending on the data in it

Tags: php

ask help to you programmers more experienced than me for a problem plaguing me for weeks.

```html
<table class="table-bordered table hover table-striped" id="grades_degree">
  <tr>
  <td >COURSES TAKEN</td>
  <td rel='a'>FALL 2013</td>
  <td rel='b'>WINTER 2014</td>  
  <td rel='c'>SPRING 2014</td>
  <td rel='d'>SUMMER 2014</td>
  <td rel='e'>FALL 2014</td>
  <td rel='f'>WINTER 2015</td>
  <td rel='g'>SPRING 2015</td>
  <td rel='h'>SUMMER 2015</td>
  <td rel='i'>FALL 2015</td>
  <td rel='j'>WINTER 2016</td>
  <td rel='k'>SPRING 2016</td>
  <td rel='l'>FALL 2016</td>
  <td rel='m'>GREEN 2014</td>
  <td rel='n'>ORANGE 2015</td>
  <td rel='o'>RED 2015</td>
  <td rel='p'>YELLOW 2015</td>
  <td rel='q'>BLUE 2015</td>
  <td rel='r'>GREEN 2015</td>
  <td rel='s'>ORANGE 2016</td>
  <td rel='t'>RED 2016</td>
  <td rel='u'>WHITE 2016</td>
  <td>GPA</td>
  <td>CREDITS</td>
 
</tr>

    
<?php       
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM grades WHERE student_id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row["course"]."</td>";
echo "<td rel='a'>".$row["fall2013"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='b'>".$row["winter2014"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='c'>".$row["spring2014"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='d'>".$row["summer2014"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='e'>".$row["fall2014"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='f'>".$row["winter2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='g'>".$row["spring2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='h'>".$row["summer2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='i'>".$row["fall2015"] ."</td>";  
echo "<td rel='j'>".$row["winter2016"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='k'>".$row["spring2016"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='l'>".$row["fall2016"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='m'>".$row["green2014"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='n'>".$row["orange2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='o'>".$row["red2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='p'>".$row["yellow2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='q'>".$row["blue2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='r'>".$row["green2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='s'>".$row["orange2015"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='t'>".$row["red2016"] ."</td>";
echo "<td rel='u'>".$row["white2016"] ."</td>";
echo "<td>".str_replace(',','.',$row["gpa"]) ."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row["credits"] ."</td>";     
echo "</tr>";
}
} 
?> 
</table>
```

You have probably already figured out what effect I try.

I would like to have a php code that allows me to delete the entire column [Only Seasons Label], if the "entire column" (every single cell) has no value (exclude the first row).

Considerations:
If a cell, at any height contains value, the column must not be deleted. Practically this table has a matrix structure which the labels are in the first column and first row.

Developer language: php. I'm junior/intermediate coder.

Comment: One simple approach could be to have an array of "visibility flags" for the columns.  You could loop through the entire result set to set the flags (have them default to false and then set each one to true when a value is found in that column), and then use the flags to output the table.  Though I'm struggling to think of a way to do this that doesn't involve looping over the entire table twice (once to set the flags, again to output the data).  If performance isn't a problem, it's certainly a straightforward approach.

Comment: I prefer the result by the performance, also because I need to then generate a pdf. Thank attention to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you need is an array to keep track if a column has had a value  after printing all of the rows.

I'm using just 3 columns to make the code more readable.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row["course"]."</td>";
    echo "<td rel='a'>".$row["fall2013"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td rel='b'>".$row["winter2014"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td rel='c'>".$row["spring2014"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".str_replace(',','.',$row["gpa"]) ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["credits"] ."</td>";     
    echo "</tr>";

    // the following lines check if the cell of a specific column has a value
    if ($count['a']!= "") $count['a']++; // If it is not empty it adds 1 to the count of that column
    if ($count['b']!= "") $count['b']++; 
    if ($count['c']!= "") $count['c']++;
  }
    foreach ($count as $rel => $total) {
      if ($total == 0){ // if Total count equals zero, it means that the $rel column never had a value in any of the rows
        echo "the column $rel has no values and should not appear" // for testing only
        // you now have the identity of the column to hide --> $rel 
        // here you hide the column with jquery or javascript 
      }
    }
}
```

the line

```
if ($count['a']!= "") $count['a']++;
```

is the same as

```
if ($count['a']!= "") {
  $count['a']++;    
}
```

but saves space.

NOTE: This works if the cell is empty or NULL, but not with a space or anything else.

FINAL NOTE:  if you assign an id or a class to the cells it will simplify the process of hiding the cells with css and javascrit

This approach takes into account performance, it only loops once a simple array of integers to check if the cell should be hidden. 
It is easier to delete  unused columns, than doing 2 full loops of all the data to see which columns should not be printed from the beginning.

Comment: I am grateful for your reflection. I will test it.

Comment: to hide the column there are many ways to do it. Search in the answers of Stackoverflow to see many examples.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php       
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM grades WHERE student_id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$results_grades[] = $row; 
}

}
echo "<table class='table-bordered table hover table-striped' id='grades_degree'>";
foreach($results_grades as $value) {
echo "<tr>";
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        if ($val!="") {
       echo "<td>".$key."</td><td>   ".$val."</td>";
    }
        }
     echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Reflecting on the solution I managed to get a multidimensional array that allowed me, with a very dirty code, even to get the desired effect. 
A small step forward.